# Unreasonable values obtained for a simplified helicopter in equilibrium

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, drag

I'm attempting to analyse a simple model of a helicopter. For one of my equations, I'm summing the forces in the x direction (forward motion). There are only really two forces acting on the helicopter, the lift from the propeller being projected forward due to the tilt of the helicopter alpha, and the drag induced. When using both the lift and drag equations from the NASA website, and using the closest values I can find for constants, I get really really weird values.

$m\ddot{x}= \frac{1}{2} \rho A_{MR} C_L \Omega_{MR}^2 r_{MR}^2 (\frac{\pi}{30})^2 sin(\alpha) - \frac{1}{2} C_D \rho \dot{x}^2 A_B$

Where ρ is the density of air, and CL and CD are the drag and lift coefficients. When I assume $\ddot{x} = 0$, I get really small values like 22RPM to travel at 100km/h? I converted velocity to RPM in the equation.

I find that the drag force applied is incredibly small compared to the force applied by the helicopter, where the drag will only be 100~200N while the rotor force can be 100,000s of Newtons. I assume the equations I'm using are correct but I'm truly lost.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/rocket/drageq.html

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/rocket/lifteq.html

Comment: Use latex where possible for formulas.